# Given a point on the surface of an OBB, return normal of the face

Tags: c++, mathematics, bounding-boxes, raytracing

So I have this class `OBB` which implements a `test` function that determines whether a ray hits it. If it does, a passed in struct is assigned a bunch of variables:

```
struct HitData
{
    float   t;
    Color   color;
    Shape* lastShape = nullptr;
    Vec lastNormal;
}
```

The last member, `Vec lastNormal;` is supposed to get its value from the class'

`normal(Vec& point)` function.

Here's where I'm drawing a complete blank. I.e. I cant seem to find any obvious (or non-obvious) solutions to how to determine the normal. 
Essentially what I want to do is identify which of the 6 planes the point lies on. In theory I could brute-force it and just do an intersection test against all the planes but that just seems unnecessarily expensive.
The OBB is defined by a center, three basis vectors and their half-lengths.

Any idea how I could approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds conceptually simple to me, but I don't know how it could be optimized. The idea would be:

- Calculate **v = point - center**;
- Project **v** into your OBB's basis, obtaining **v'**;
- Find the coordinate of **v'** that has the largest absolute value;
- Zero the other coordinates out, obtaining **d**;
- Project **d** back into the world basis, obtaining **d'**;
- Normalize **d'**. That's your normal! :)

This works because the OBB is a unit cube in its own basis. We subdivide space into six unbounded pyramids that each correspond to a face. Determining which face the point is on is the same as determining which pyramid it is in. And that is pretty simple: just find its predominant coordinate.